# can any solve what is wrong with this please?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
create table account_type
(
acct_type number(3) primary key,
acct_desc Varchar2(30) not null CHECK (acct_desc IN('savings','salary','current','credit')),
acct_wd_limit number(10)
);

create sequence acct_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER acct_pk
BEFORE INSERT ON account_type 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.acct_type IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT acct_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.acct_type
  FROM   account_type;
END;
```

i am getting an error on the line before insert on account_type. no idea why

I also tried doing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER acct_pk
BEFORE INSERT ON account_type 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.id IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT acct_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id 
  FROM   account_type;
END;
```

Even doing this is giving me an error

```
create sequence acct_pk
start with 1
increment by 1
max value 999
min value 1
no cycle;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your sequence name in the create sequence should be acct_seq.

Comment: How can we answer the question if you don't show us the error messages that result from trying to run your statements? Maybe your syntax is wrong. Maybe you don't have the correct permissions to create tables and sequences. A lot of different things can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since the author tagged the question with [oracle10g](/questions/tagged/oracle10g), she can't use `sequence_name.nextVal` in PL/SQL. Solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER acct_pk
  BEFORE INSERT ON account_type 
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_acct_type NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF :new.acct_type IS NULL THEN
    SELECT acct_seq.NEXTVAL
      INTO   v_acct_type
    FROM   dual;
    :new.acct_type := v_acct_type;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the solution but the declare statement is still giving me an error such as                                      ERROR at line 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored3.   FOR EACH ROW
4. DECLARE
5.   v_acct_type NUMBER;
6. BEGIN
7.   IF :new.acct_type IS NULL THEN

Comment: I basically need to auto generate the primary key for account_type

Comment: @carolinepereira Edit your original question, post exactly what you tried to execute and show us the errors you get. I see in your question that you have additional `SEQUENCE` called `acct_pk`, the same name you use for the trigger. Try my answer but give the trigger a different name and change the name of the sequence in the trigger to match the name of the trigger you are actually using.